# in c# when trying to add a node to a queue cant use .Next

Tags: c#, queue

Trying to add and delete nodes from a queue in C#. However when trying to use `front.Next` I get a compiler error that the definition is not contained.

```
class Queue<T>
{
    int count = 0;
    Node<T> front = null;
    Node<T> end = null;

    public void Enqueue(T obj)
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            front = new Node<T>(obj);
        }
        else 
        {
            Node<T> newEnd = new Node<T>(obj);
            newEnd.Next = end;
            count++;
            end = newEnd;
        }
    }

    public T Dequeue(T obj)
    {
        Node<T> newFront = new Node<T>(obj);
        newFront = front.Next;
        count--;
        front = newFront;
        return front;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T> ?

Comment: Look into [LinkedListNode(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf4c754.aspx)

Comment: Where is `Node<T>` defined?

Comment: Node<T> is not part of the .Net libraries. Where did you get it from?

Comment: Node<T> is a separate class

Comment: @Joey Saxon Right - not an especially helpful comment, so let's try this - does it have a `Next` property?

Comment: No :S but just writing one

Comment: So, wait. You haven't written a `Next` property yet, and you're wondering why you get compilation errors?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why you're trying to recreate the already existing `Queue` collection in .NET?

To answer your problem though, you're missing a `Next` method in your object, so the compiler is telling you that it can't find `Next`.

**You should really consider using the [existing `Queue` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/055sfc3z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) though.**

Comment: my guess: it's homework.

Comment: Unless, of course, it's an exam/homework/class assignment. It looks fascinatingly a lot like one of my old pascal-assignments to build a single-linked list.

Comment: @hometoast Good shout, added it in the edit :)

Comment: @J.Steen Good shout, check my **disclaimer** edit ;)

Comment: Even if it's homework, it's OK to ask/answer on SO. Just don't write a copy/paste-ready solution, that's all.

Comment: @ken2k Ah really? Then i've taken out the disclaimer :)

Comment: Yeah, my comment was just to note that this answer might, in fact, be invalid for the OPs specific circumstances. In all other cases I'd totally agree. =)

Comment: im not asking for code just as to why i get the erro

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments you get the compilation error because you have written a `Node<T>` class that does not implement a `Next` property.

Was the error message given by the compiler confusing in some way?